# Timer using web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I'm trying to use a Timer in my web application, but cant seem to make it work. Here is my code:

VB Code:

```vb
Public Class WebForm1 
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page 

    Protected WithEvents Label1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label 

    Private t As New System.Timers.Timer(2000) 

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
        AddHandler t.Elapsed, AddressOf TimerFired 
        t.Enabled = True 

    End Sub 

    Public Sub TimerFired(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
        ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) 
            Label1.Text = Now 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Here I'm trying to change the text of the label every 2 seconds.

Comment: Do you know the difference between server-side and client-side code? Once the page has been rendered and sent, the client won't know anything of further server-side processing. Also please make your code more readable.

Comment: In the future when posting questions, please refrain from including tags in the question title and use the code formatting built into the editor.

Comment: Why do you need to save it every 2 seconds?

Comment: i trying to learn how can i use the timer in my code in vb.net

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to learn and study the fundamental difference between server and client code.

By the provided code I think you need to update a label every 2 seconds withe the current date-time.
For partial rendering and update of a page (and much more!) there is AJAX, and related timer.
Please take a look to this good example about, I think, your needs:

http://www.aspxcode.net/free-asp-net-ajax-source-code.aspx?Topics=How%20to%20Use%20AJAX%20Timer

Comment: If the question is solved please mark the answer. If you need more example please tell me.